# how can I swipe pageview with holding background image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to hold background image and swipe pageview screen.

However, it seems that I can't swipe if I put image file(I can do only when I delete background image) even though you can see the pageindicator.

[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXYaL.jpg)

please let me know how to do it. Is there any way to solve it? I don't know what I missed here.

```
import 'package:eseowakorean/page/secondpage/add_image_profile1.dart';
import 'package:eseowakorean/page/secondpage/add_image_profile2.dart';
import 'package:eseowakorean/page/secondpage/add_image_profile3.dart';
import 'package:eseowakorean/page/secondpage/add_image_profile4.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

import '../../widgets/text_widgets.dart';

class AddInformationOnBoarding extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddInformationOnBoarding({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddInformationOnBoarding> createState() =>
      _AddInformationOnBoardingState();
}

class _AddInformationOnBoardingState extends State<AddInformationOnBoarding> {
  PageController _controller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView(
            controller: _controller,
            children: [
              AddImageProfile1(),
              AddImageProfile2(),
              AddImageProfile3(),
              AddImageProfile4(),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            // alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'assets/home.jpg',
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),

            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      SvgPicture.asset('assets/Skip.svg'),
                      // poppinsTextWidget('hi')
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    poppinsTextWidget('Let' 's Talk About You!', fontSize: 20)
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment(0, 0.75),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                SmoothPageIndicator(controller: _controller, count: 4),
              ],
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are containing everything within the same stack. Add the image itself in another Stack widget.

Try this example:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            "assets/home.jpg",
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [
              PageView(
                controller: _controller,
                children: [
                  AddImageProfile1(),
                  AddImageProfile2(),
                  AddImageProfile3(),
                  AddImageProfile4(),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        SvgPicture.asset('assets/Skip.svg'),
                        // poppinsTextWidget('hi')
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      poppinsTextWidget('Let' 's Talk About You!', fontSize: 20)
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment(0, 0.75),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    SmoothPageIndicator(controller: _controller, count: 4),
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but where do I have to put another stack? can you please write down it?

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer for you. Can you give this a try? @jonghwan

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. when I swipe first page, I can see the background image a bit, but when I swipe I can see only addImageProfile pages @Texv